# How to write a ZeroMQ Load Balancing server that can use Logstash as clients and is non-blocking?

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, logstash, zeromq

I have some logstash instances that speak to a micro-service using ZeroMQ. The problem arises when one particular call takes too much time, the server blocks and results in ZeroMQ timeouts on the logstash end.

I have been reading [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:chapter3) and turns out that there are ways to write a server that uses a LRU (Least recently used) Paradigm. Can anybody point out any pointers that can be helpful for such a use case.

Some points that I would like to highlight, are :

1. I have very less control over the client (since logstash doesn't offer the full API of ZeroMQ).
2. The server has to be non blocking, multi-threaded(or multi-process) and should handle that within it's use case.

[This](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:lbbroker) is the reference code I am using. Any helpful tips or pointers for such a use-case?

Comment: Can you clarify the architecture?  The micro-service sends information to Logstash via ZeroMQ?  What type of sockets?  What is the "call"?

Comment: The architecture is a simple REQ REP model, just that there are multiple logstash instances speaking to one server (so I want this to be multi-threaded) to handle the load better. Logstash sends a string, and the server replies a response.

A simulation of my case can be : 
logstash instances : logstashA, logstashB, logstashC
server : server

logstash events send 1,2,3 (numeric values) and the server replies with one, two, three(strings).